# Nothing to export, 0/7 objects selected?

Tags: objects, export, collada

When I try to export this item as a collada, nothing exports. It will sometimes go through with the export (when I export as collada - default) but nothing is actually in the file. When I try to export as collada - avastar I get : 'Nothing to export' and the option to export 'Selection only' is grayed out.

I noticed that when the item is selected, in the top bar it says Objects : 0/7 which I assume means its not registering the object even though its physically there.

Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide your .blend file

Comment: This file uses Avastar - [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2824" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2824/)

Comment: I've tried exporting as collada and it worked, and then imported the exported one and it worked as well.

Comment: I even tried exporting with a newer version of Blender - no success. It may be because of the Avastar addon?

Comment: Not sure, Do you want me to send you the exported collada .dae model?

Comment: Sure but I'm curious as to why when selected now.. it says Verts 0 - Faces 0 - Tris 0 - Objects 0/7 - Lamps 0/1 ... is there a setting that's wrong that im missing?

Comment: FYI I opened a previous iteration of this skirt and it is saying there is an object that is exportable. So some setting must have changed. I also tried to open the newest version of the skirt in a blender install that did not have the Avastar addon as I thought that might be causing the problem, and it was still unexportable.

Comment: that's weird as I was able to export it on my machine

Answer (score 1):

I identified that there is an issue when I import a collada, and then save the file as .blend. When I reopen the .blend file, the collada object is not editable like shown above. How to fix it, I'm still not sure. I had to delete the object and re-import the collada, losing my rigging and uvs.

Comment: Don't answer your question when you want to give more details since it's not an answer to the question. It's better to edit the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Render Layers -> Layer -> Scene 
Make sure the boxes, of which layer you want to export the meshes from, are checked. You can select multiple boxes while holding down SHIFT.